# How can I access a linux box at home in my browser at work?

Tags: ssh

I want to be able to use taskwarrior at work.  But the computers at work don't allow me to install anything, they all run Win XP, and IE...

So, I would like to somehow SSH to a linux box at home, and do it through a browser.  I should mention that I'd be working with a dynamic IP.

Is this possible? If so, what is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: See https://www.noip.com/free/ or http://freedns.afraid.org/ for dynamic DNS.

Comment: Answers already cover other stuff, but for the 'shell in browser' part, you might want to check out `shellinabox`

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach would be to set up a SOCKS proxy via an SSH tunnel. In order for that to work correctly, you would need to use a service to discover and update your home's external IP, there are a number of free and paid services that provide this.

A script I use for this is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SSH_HOST="me@myhomeIP -p XXX -i $HOME/.ssh/mykey"

up(){
    ssh -f -N -D 8080 -M -S /tmp/ssh_tunnel_%h.sock -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes $SSH_HOST && \
    printf '%s\n' "ssh tunnel started successfully" || \
    printf '%s\n' "ssh tunnel failed to start"
}

down(){
    ssh -S /tmp/ssh_tunnel_%h.sock -O exit $SSH_HOST
}

if [[ "$1" = "up" ]]; then
    up && chromium --proxy-server="socks://127.0.0.1:8080" &
elif [[ "$1" = "down" ]]; then
    down
else
    printf '%s\n' "Tunnel is not running…"
fi
```

The first function, `up`, sets up the SSH tunnel and then, once it is running, Chromium is started with the option to use the tunnel as a proxy.

You can configure Firefox to connect over the tunnel if you would  prefer to use it. I have no idea about IE.

Answer (score 1):

If you using router at home (ADSL or Cable), you need to connect to the ip of the router (192.168.1.1 depends wich model you use, you can find on the Internet username and passsword),
When you connect find NAT and port forwarding option, and there add local ip of your linux box and add port that you use for ssh (default 22), Save and go to the Internet and type on google wahtismyip, then try to ssh on that static address. This depends from dhcp of your ISP provider how they are configured leased time, also you can ask them to give you the static address.